# Complementing bits in a register in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86-64, bit, cpu-registers, complement

How does one complement an individual bit or bits in a register?

Comment: Which assembly language? What have you tried?

Comment: x86. I have tried using NEG but something seems to not be working.

Comment: Think of how you would do it in C. Then do the same in assembly. You will need to create a mask.

Comment: XOR would be a good instruction to use.

Comment: I'm quite new to all of this so excuse my stumbling through all of this. For example, if I wanted to complement bits 0 and 1 in the RAX register, would it be NOT RAX, 0xffffffc?

Comment: I just realized how ridiculous that first answer was.
How about XOR RAX, 0xfffffffc?

Comment: @Joachim: as that seems like a good answer, why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

[XOR](http://zsmith.co/intel_x.html#xor) would be a good instruciton to use for flipping individual bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a XOR and NOT instruction respectively, for example.

Your number is 1111, and you need complement of 0 and 3 position like this 0110, so:

```
mov al, 1111
xor al, 0110
not al
int 3
```

This should change al register of 1111 to 0110